# Tooltips CSS stopped working

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I had a tooltips on my icon images to create a hover effect caption. It was styled just the way I want, but it stopped working somewhere along the line and looks like a basic Microsoft notification near your cursor. I want to say this happened when I added multiple groups of tooltips, but I'm not entirely sure. Plus everything is already in classes so there isn't any IDs to break when I add more.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.concentrationIcons {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 14%;
}

.tooltip {
  color: #e9cecf !important;
  font-family: Raleway !important;
}

.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #36193a !important;
}

.iconImg {
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="concentrationIcons">
  <img class="iconImg tooltipDesign" src="assets/designIcon.png" data- toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Integration of art 
             and communication">
  <!-- DESIGN -->
  <img class="iconImg tooltipBus" src="assets/busIcon.png" data- toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Using technology to 
           maximize marketing">
  <!-- BUSTECH -->
  <img class="iconImg tooltipCom" src="assets/commIcon.png" data- toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Moving viewers 
              through a story">
  <!-- COMMUNICATIONS -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for it?

Comment: `data-toggle=` not `data- toggle=`

Answer (score 0):

There is white space between data toggle

```
data- toggle
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

 <img class="iconImg tooltipDesign" src="assets/designIcon.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Integration of art 
             and communication">

Instead of

<img class="iconImg tooltipDesign" src="assets/designIcon.png" data- toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Integration of art 
             and communication">
```